# IDE best supportive for sparse many line code

Tags: software-development, text-editor, ide

I use Allman brace placement. Most of the time the code I write is sparse, involves a lot of scrolling up and down. Clearly an IDE that has multiple windows viewing the same file is a must. Quick code folding helps. Breadcrumbs. A minimal minimap on the side helps with navigation. I'm looking for an IDE that makes it easier to look at different parts of your program, especially when programs are more than several hundred lines. Any plugins that make the process easier. What IDE is best suited for the above needs?

Comment: I know this is *software* recommendations, but if it weren't I'd suggest getting a 4K monitor with as large a screen as you can reasonably handle. My main Terminal window is 90 lines × 110 characters, and the monitor can support 3 windows like that side by side.  If my eyes weren't so old, I could use a much smaller font. A few hundred dollars will pay for itself in productivity almost at once.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) editor is not an IDE, but it supports plugins, and LSP Client plugin exists. With LSP plugin and LSP Server for C++ language, you will get partly what is needed.
https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText_plugins#LSP_Client

Then CudaText can split single editor window to 2 parts (for the same file).
Menu "View / Split tab / Split vertically".

[image: C++ file opened]

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or it's FOSS sibling [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) is one of the best *gratis* option available today.

It can handle large code files, built in it has the following features you've mentioned:

- [Folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding)
- [minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_minimap)
- [breadcrumbs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_breadcrumbs)
- [side-by-side editing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_side-by-side-editing) which also allows to have multiple live views of the same file.

Together with all the bells and whistles needed in an IDE, the feature list is huge, and the release notes always introduce something new.

And probably one of the most interesting implementation of this excellent editor, is the self-hosted web version of it - [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server), which makes it so accessible that all you'll need is a browser to access the editor.